# Дублирование кода в циклах java

Tags: java

Подскажите, как в подобном методе избежать дублирование кода?

```
public static int[] findNumbers(int n) {
    int[] result = new int[(int) Math.sqrt(n)];
    for (int i = 1; i * i < n; i++) {
        result[i - 1] = i * i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: С этим методом все в порядке, тут нет дублирования.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а мне вот говорят, что есть, i*i я так понимаю дублируется.

Comment: `int j = 0;
     for (int i = 1;  (j = i * i) < n; i++) {
         result[i - 1] = j; }`  хех.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну это не стоит того. экономить лишнюю операцию умножения за счет потери читабельности.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov смотря какие числа использовать.

Comment: Накидал тест для проверки, https://gist.github.com/izebit/11ed9c0f599de9c584f7c8418a61ec45. Оказалось что они почти равны. разница в приделах погрешности.

Comment: Зачем i * i < n, если i можно сравнить с размером массива, или сохранить значение выражения (int) Math.sqrt(n)

Comment: @RuslanP. похоже на то, что нужно, спасибо

Comment: Как вариант модификации Алексея Шиманского for (int i = 1, j = 1; j < n; i++, j = i*i) { result[i - 1] = j; }

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно ещё `j` в цикл зафигачить, да и не только. Как-то так: `for (int j, i = 1; (j = i * i) < n; result[i++ - 1] = j);`

Comment: @AlexChermenin эх, рановато. Надо было еще 13 дней подождать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да вот не вытерпел)))